# TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.connect) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, react-hooks, mocking

I have a component where the only logic is a conditional:

```
const SuccessPage = () => {
  const { urls } = useSelector(getFeatures);

  return urls ? <Success /> : <Failure />;
};

export default SuccessPage;
```

I then created some tests for this but for some reason I get `TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.connect) is not a function` . Maybe I have't mocked useSelector correctly? I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { getFeatures } from '../../../selectors/index';

import Success from './success.react';
import Failure from './failure.react';
import SuccessPage from './success-page.react';

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector: jest.fn((fn) => fn()),
}));
jest.mock('../../../selectors/index');

describe('SuccessPage', () => {
  it('should render Success if getFeatures returns true', () => {
    getFeatureFlags.mockReturnValue(true);

    const wrapper = shallow(<SuccessPage />);

    expect(wrapper.find(Success).exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should render Failure if getFeatures returns false', () => {
    getFeatureFlags.mockReturnValue(false);

    const wrapper = shallow(<SuccessPage />);

    expect(wrapper.find(Failure).exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```